# d3.js guidance on interactive scrolling an svg element

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have created [this](http://www.d3geometry.com/functions) functionality using d3.js and mathjs that draws a curve and then draws the tangent of the curve on mouseover.  The source code is [here](https://github.com/dagda1/d3-geometry/blob/master/app/js/components/function-plot.js).

What I am interested in doing is allowing the user to scroll a cubic curve for example by dragging the x axis and then redrawing the graph.

Can anyone give me some high level guidance on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use d3 brush for this implementation.

Documentation: [SVG-Controls](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls)

Sample Reference : [Focus+Context via Brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)